# How to get index of list of dict and add dict to each index?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a json file with below structure:

```
{
    "Premier League": {
        "abbreviation": "EN_PR",
        "id": 1.0,
        "seasons": [
            {
                "label": "2019/20",
                "id": 274.0
            },
            {
                "label": "2018/19",
                "id": 210.0
            }
        ]
    },
    "UEFA Champions League": {
        "abbreviation": "EU_CL",
        "id": 2.0,
        "seasons": [
            {
                "label": "Champions League Season 2019/2020",
                "id": 288.0
            },
            {
                "label": "2018/19",
                "id": 214.0
            },
        ]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, while iterating, index each `season_id`, later get info about the `season_id` by making a request with it to an other data-source and lastly add the info gotten to each `seasons_id`. So it get's something like this, and do that for each `season_id` in seasons. Below is an example help you illustrate what I mean by indexing each `season id` in `seasons`.

```
{
        "Premier League": {
            "abbreviation": "EN_PR",
            "id": 1.0,
            "seasons": [
                {
                    "label": "2019/20",
                    "id": 274.0,
                    "teams" :{
                         "Arsenal":{
                             "Players":{}
                                   },

                              }
                },
```

**The question is:** How do I Iterate over the the seasons list for each parent key and add info to each season_id?

Below prints each season-id, but I'm not sure how to access them and add info to them.

```
 for key in parent_key:
    seasons = file[key]['seasons']
    for season in seasons:
        print(season['id'])
```

Comment: Did you realize that neither `teams`, nor `Arsenal` are present in the input JSON? How could we show how to transform a JSON to have them magically appear in the result?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear with my question, I will reframe it! Thank you

Comment: This is not a good data structure for the thing that you are trying to do.  Are you tied to the dict-of-dict-of-dict-of-dict design?

Comment: @Scott I'm absolutly not tied to it, but my question doesn't explain why I'm using this approach. In the simpliest way I can explain it is that I need to be able to create a folder structure that makes sense, picture "league"-"Seasons"-"Teams""-Players". And at the same time be able to get all ids to make requests without looking through every folder. But I'm very happy to hear suggestions since I don't know much of data-structures! Thank you!

Comment: @Scott All data is also scraped from an API that has structured is data in json-format, so it's convenient to use dicts

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you may find that if you are frequently updating items by id, then parsing your data into the following format is much easier:

```
leagues = { 
    1: {
        "name": "Premier_League",
        "seasons": { 
            274: {
                "label": "2019/20"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, given a `league_id` and a `season_id`, you can easily access the season associated with it as `leagues[league_id]["seasons"][season_id]`.  You can also update info in that season with:

```
league_id = 1
season_id = 274
leagues[league_id]["seasons"][season_id]["teams"] = { "Arsenal": { "players": {}}}
print(leagues)

# {1: {'name': 'Premier_League', 'seasons': {274: {'label': '2019/20', 'teams': {'Arsenal': {'players': {}}}}}}}
```

In general, `dicts` are good for fast and simple lookup when you know the key that you are trying to look up.

Comment: Thank you for the input! Right now I'm trying to build a class that takes the league_id as a parameter and updates the whole league! While trying to solve one thing I either get a better idea halfway trough or run into a wall.. Thank you for taking your time to write it up!